# Is Nestedness necessary in Cantor's intersection theorem

Tags: general-topology

The standard statement of Cantor's intersection theorem is that, in any topological space, a nested sequence of compact, closed, nonempty sets also has a nonempty intersection.

What confuses me now is that why is "nested" needed here? For example, if I have a sequence of compact, closed sets $A_1\supset A_2\supset\dotsm$, I can simply take $B_n=A_1\cap\dotsm\cap A_n$. Since $A_n$ are assumed to be closed, a finite intersection of closed sets is closed, so $B_n$ are nested and closed. And also $\bigcap_n B_n=\bigcap_n A_n$. So if I remove "nested" from the theorem statement, it would still be true.

So my questions are:

(1) Is my reasoning above correct?

(2) Is there any "counterexample" to the Cantor intersection theorem where "nested" is violated?

Comment: You just need to assume every finite intersection is non-empty

Comment: @peek-a-boo Ok, so if I change the "nested" to the $B_n$'s being non-empty it'd still work. So essentially there is nothing else special about assuming "nested"?

Comment: What is special about being nested is it implies the finite intersection is nonempty. The result is obviously false in general if nestedness is dropped without any other property being added, eg if all the $A_i$ are disjoint (so that your $B_i$ are all empty)

Comment: sure. Except if you state it as "all finite intersections are non-empty", then you can allow yourself an arbitrary indexed family $\{A_i\}_{i\in I}$ of closed compact sets, rather than just sequences. Have I ever had to use this more general result? Nope, but it sure is fun to know.

Comment: @peek-a-boo Many thanks for your comments :) In fact I did come across a use of this more general result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not correct. If you have a sequence $(A_n)$ of (nonempty!) compact closed sets, you can define $B_n = \bigcap_{i=1]}^n A_i$. The $B_n$ are compact closed sets, the sequence $(B_n)$ is nested and $\bigcap_n A_n = \bigcap_n B_n$. But in general some $B_n$ may be empty, thus you cannot conclude that $\bigcap_n A_n \ne \emptyset$. If $(A_n)$ is nested, we have $B_n = A_n \ne \emptyset$.

As an example take the subsets $A_n = \{n\}$ of $\mathbb R$.

The assumption that you really need is known as the *finite intersection property*:

A family $\mathcal A = (A_i)_{i \in I}$ of sets has the *finite intersection property* if all finite intersections of members of in $\mathcal A$ are nonempty.

We can prove

**Theorem 1.** Let $\mathcal A = (A_i)_{i \in I}$ be a family of closed compact subsets of a space $X$. If  $\mathcal A$ has the finite intersection property, then $\bigcap_{i \in J} A_i \ne \emptyset$.

Note that this is also true under the weaker assumption that all $A_i$ are closed and *one* $A_{i_0}$ is compact. Then the $A'_i = A_i \cap A_{i_0}$ form a family of compact closed subsets having the finite intersection property. Since $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i = \bigcap_{i \in I} A'_i$, we are done.

Theorem 1. follows easily from

**Theorem 2.** A space $X$ is compact if and only if each family of closed subsets $\mathcal A = (A_i)_{i \in I}$ which has finite intersection property
has nonempty intersection  $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$.

The proof is easy: Observe that open covers $\mathcal U = (U_i)_{i \in I}$ of  $X$ are in $1$-$1$ correspondence with families $\mathcal A = (A_i)_{i \in I}$ of closed subsets having empty intersection $\bigcap_{i \in I} A_i$ (take the complements of the members of such families). Finite subcovers of $\mathcal U$ correspond to finite subfamilies of $\mathcal A$ which have empty intersection.